# get unique strings by function findall

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract unique strings from file(*.txt). But my code written so that the same line repeated. I need to get each unique string issued once.??

```
import re
f=open('C:\\isg-2000.txt')

p=f.readlines()
print len(p)
for i in range(len(p)):
  S = re.findall(r'set vrouter \".+?\"',p[i])
  if S:

    print S
```

such output:

```
4438
['set vrouter "untrust-vr"']
['set vrouter "trust-vr"']
['set vrouter "UntrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "CNDT-vr"']
['set vrouter "MGT"']
['set vrouter "MGT"']
['set vrouter "MGT"']
['set vrouter "untrust-vr"']
['set vrouter "trust-vr"']
['set vrouter "UntrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "CNDT-vr"']
['set vrouter "MGT"']
['set vrouter "untrust-vr"']
['set vrouter "trust-vr"']
['set vrouter "UntrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"']
['set vrouter "CNDT-vr"']
['set vrouter "MGT"']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set` with a generator expression:

```
import re
with open('C:\\isg-2000.txt') as f:
   r = re.compile(r'set vrouter \".+?\"')
   unique_matches = set(m for line in f for m in r.findall(line))
```

Note that sets don't preserve order, if order matters use `collections.OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict
...
unique_matches = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(m for line in f for m in r.findall(line)))
```

Comment: Thank you!Essentially correct. but such output:
set(['set vrouter "CNDT-vr"', 'set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"',....why the string starts with 'set'. how to get rid of 'set'. display with each row substring

Comment: @user3214034 That's how a `set` is represented in Python2, in Python3 this has been changed to `{...}`. To get just the string separated by comma use: `print ', '.join(unique_matches)`. Or if you want to print each item on a new line then use: `for item in unique_matches: print item`

Comment: Ashwini Chaudhary, you happen to know how the same but the language C#?? my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21696774/get-unique-strings-by-function-findall-c-sharp

Comment: @user3214034 Sorry, no idea about C#.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
import re
f=open('C:\\Users\\vlazarev\\Desktop\\isg-2000-1-2013-08-14_for_amt.txt')

s = set(re.findall(r'set vrouter \".+?\"', f.read()))
print s
```

Comment: Thank you!Essentially correct. but such output:
set(['set vrouter "CNDT-vr"', 'set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"',....why the string starts with 'set'. how to get rid of 'set'. display with each row substring

Comment: You can convert the set to list, or do all kinds of manipulation later.