# Get unique strings C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to extract unique strings from file(*.txt). But my code s written so that the same line s repeated. I need to get each unique string issued once.

**My code :**

```
OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
  string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
  foreach (var line in lines)
  {
    var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern);
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
      if (match.Success)
          textBox1.AppendText(match.Value + '\n');
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
set vrouter R1
set vrouter R1
set vrouter R2
set vrouter R3
set vrouter R2
set vrouter R4
set vrouter R4
set vrouter R5
set vrouter R1
set vrouter R6
set vrouter R4
set vrouter R3
set vrouter R5
```

**Changed code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
  if (opendialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    var lines = File.ReadLines(opendialog.FileName);
    string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";

    var matches = 
        lines.SelectMany(line=> Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
             .Cast<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success)
             .Select(m => m.Value)
             .Distinct();

    foreach (String match in matches)
    {
      textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
    }
  }
}
```

It work correctly!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to exclude duplicates. You can use `Enumerable.Distinct`.

Note that you need to use `File.ReadAllLines` instead of `File.ReadLines` if you want to use the outer `foreach` since `ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` under the hood which gets disposed on the first `foreach` enumeration.

For example:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Cast<Match>()
            .Where(m => m.Success)
            .Select(m => m.Value)
            .Distinct();

foreach (String match in matches)
    textBox1.AppendText(match + Environment.NewLine);
```

If you want unique matches across all lines(here you can stay with `File.ReadLines`):

```
var matches = lines
    .SelectMany(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Cast<Match>())
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .Distinct();
```

To clarify my second approach, this requires no outer foreach at all since `SelectMany` already replaces that by selecting all matches of all lines. So you only need one `foreach` to output the result.

Comment: I have changed my code according with your remark. I added it here.  but i have error.   maybe i done error somewhere??

Comment: @user3214034: i seee what the problem is. `File.ReadLines` uses a `StreamReader` under the hood. This is disposed as soon as you execute the (LINQ-)query which happens at the inner `foreach`. So you either have to use my second approach which returns unique matches across **all lines** (as opposed to the first approach which you have used). Or you have to use `File.ReadAllLines` instead which reads all lines into a memory(`string[]`) first. Note that my second approach doesn't need that outer `foreach` at all since `SelectMany` already selects all matches of all lines.